# ListBox | Выделить элемент списка

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Есть ListBox с Images. Пользователь выделяет мышкой изображение в ListBox и стрелкой на клавиатуре перемещает вправо по списку (Из Image используется Source текущего элемента для увеличения). В текущей реализации не устанавливает на позицию текущего индекса. При текущем верном индексе устанавливает выделение на +1 от перемещённого изображения, а если задать жестко `ContainerFromIndex(3)`, то так же устанавливает на +1, на -1 в другую сторону одинаково. Как не видит 0, между +1 и -1.

```
ListBoxPhotos.Items.Insert(Index + 2, img);
ListBoxPhotos.Items.RemoveAt(Index);
ListBoxPhotos.SelectedItem = null;
ListBoxPhotos.SelectedIndex = Index + 1;
ListBoxItem listBoxItem = ListBoxPhotos.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Index) as ListBoxItem;
listBoxItem.Focus();
```

---

```
<ListBox 
    SelectionChanged="ListBoxItemClick" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    x:Name="ListBoxPhotos"  
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    Background="#FF5CB57A" 
    BorderBrush="{x:Null}" KeyDown="StackPanel_KeyDown">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" KeyDown="StackPanel_KeyDown"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

---

Этот вариант делает что нужно, только отображается MessageBox, который тут не нужен. Каждый раз отображается и то ли фокус меняется, то ли какое свойство. Не могу понять какое свойство изменяется. Если определить, то можно его вызывать программно без MessageBox.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count; i++)
{
    object yourObject = ListBoxPhotos.Items[i];
    ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)ListBoxPhotos.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(yourObject);

    if (lbi.IsFocused)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item at index " + i.ToString() + " has the focus.");
        break;
    }
    ListBoxPhotos.SelectedIndex = Index + 1;
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = ListBoxPhotos.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ListBoxPhotos.SelectedIndex - 1) as ListBoxItem;
    listBoxItem.Focus();

}
```

Comment: Эм... А для чего это? Если вам надо чтоб `ListBox` в ряд размещал изображения, а выделение менялось стрелками вправо и влево, то просто переопределите ему `ItemsPanel` на `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>` и все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Особо ничего не изменилось, так же работает. Прикрепил xaml.

Comment: Не изменилось что? Какое поведение вы хотите? Стрелками переключать фокус или именно перемещать позицию элемента в списке? Если первое, то я вам решение сказал, если 2-е, то тут надо немного позаморочится, да. Если что-то другое, то я не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня есть логика перемещения элементов по списку на кнопках. Там всё работает нормально (только там я не определяю ListBoxItem). Здесь нужно сделать то же самое, только на кнопках клавиатуры. Подписываюсь на событие keyDown (StackPanel), получаю текущую кнопку на клавиатуре и пытаюсь перемещать по массиву элемент. Элемент перемещается только один раз, пока есть фокус от мышки, нажатия.  После перемещения фокус сбрасывается на нулевой элемент.

Comment: Вам нужно с клавиатуры при нажатии каких-то кнопок перемещать элемент по списку? Я все правильно понял?

Comment: @aepot добавил ответ.

Comment: @NorthFace я немного другой ответ готовил, интересно?

Comment: @aepot конечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перемещать элемент коллекции при нажатии кнопок не так сложно, как кажется.

Пример сделаю на базе коллекции `ObservableCollection` и привязок данных. Как я понял, вы не знакомы с шаблоном проектирования MVVM, и весь код у вас в классе окна. Поэтому покажу с настройкой датаконтекста именно туда.

Для работы кода, представленного ниже, потребуется вспомогательный класс для использования команд (их используют в WPF вместо обработчиков событий).

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

И еще маленькое перечисление

```cs
public enum Direction
{
    Backward,
    Forward
}
```

Класс окна надо доработать вот так

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
    private ICommand _moveCommand;
    private string _selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int SelectedIndex => Items.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ICommand MoveCommand => _moveCommand ?? (_moveCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (Enum.TryParse(parameter as string, out Direction direction))
        {
            int index = SelectedIndex;
            if (direction == Direction.Backward && index > 0)
            {
                Items.Move(index, index - 1);
            }
            else if (direction == Direction.Forward && index < Items.Count - 1)
            {
                Items.Move(index, index + 1);
            }
        }
    }));

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "https://image1_url",
            "https://image2_url"
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Здесь:

- Реализация интерфейса `INotifyPropertyChanged`, чтобы интерфейс мог обновляться динамически.
- `ObservableCollection<string>` - коллекция с путями для картинок для из `Source`.
- `SelectedItem`, сюда привязан выбранный элемент листбокса
- `SelectedIndex` конвертирует `SelectedItem` в ее индекс (предполагается, что все стоки в коллекции уникальны и не повторяются)
- `MoveCommand` - команда, которая вызывается при нажатии клавиш

И вот такая получится разметка

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Right" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Forward"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="Left" Command="{Binding MoveCommand}" CommandParameter="Backward"/>
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

При нажатии стрелки на клавиатуре элемент едет право или влево, как задумано. Фокус при этом сохраняется на выделенном элементе.

Клавиши для `InputBindings` можно задавать с модификаторами, например `Key="Right" Modifiers="Ctrl"`.

*Обратите внимание, у контролов даже имён нет `x:Name`, они здесь без надобности.*

Comment: `_moveCommand ` можете написать конструкцию ниже 8.0 версии? `??=` - неизвестный оператор.

Comment: @NorthFace готово.

Comment: Собрал пустой проект, отображается пустой экран. Указывал путь до `http://*.jpeg` или `C:\Users\*.jpeg`.

Comment: @NorthFace вы не забыли добавить в самом верху `INotifyPropertyChanged` для `Window`? Так же надо подключить обработчик события у окна `Loaded="Window_Loaded"` в XAML.

Comment: @NorthFace `using System.ComponentModel;` в директивах и можно просто `INotifyPropertyChanged` потом писать.

Comment: В `Window_Loaded` дебагер не заходит.

Comment: @NorthFace Значит вы его не подключили. Напишите в XAML то, что я вам выше показал, в параметрах окна, там где высота, ширина, заголовок и т.д.

Comment: @NorthFace не получается? я могу показать, если надо. Просто не ожидал, что подключение обработчика в принципе может вызвать сложности.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123497/discussion-between-north-face-and-aepot).

Answer (score 1):

Суть в следующем. У `ListBox` есть стандартное поведение перемещения по списку влево и вправо. И его необходимо перегрузить. Я этого не сделал и происходил конфликт. На данный момент можно решить так:

1. У главного `Grid` определить событие `KeyDown` с именем `OnKeyDownHandler`.

```cs
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

2. В этом методе выполнять алгоритм:

```cs
 if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        if (ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var Path = (ListBoxPhotos.SelectedItem as Image).Source.ToString();
            int Index = ListBoxPhotos.SelectedIndex;
            Image img = common.PathStringToImage(Path, (ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count));

            if (Index != ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                ListBoxPhotos.Items.Insert(Index + 2, img);
                ListBoxPhotos.Items.RemoveAt(Index);

                var item = (ListBoxItem)ListBoxPhotos.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Index + 1);
                item?.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Финальный код:

```cs
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Right)
    {
        if (ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var Path = (ListBoxPhotos.SelectedItem as Image).Source.ToString();
            int Index = ListBoxPhotos.SelectedIndex;
            Image img = common.PathStringToImage(Path, (ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count));

            if (Index != ListBoxPhotos.Items.Count - 1)
            {
                ListBoxPhotos.Items.Insert(Index + 2, img);
                ListBoxPhotos.Items.RemoveAt(Index);

                var item = (ListBoxItem)ListBoxPhotos.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(Index + 1);
                item?.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Ссылка на другой ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587270/keypress-event-equivalent-in-wpf)