# Медиаплеер - Как динамически изменять стиль элемента через код?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Во время компиляции программа создает несколько кнопок и присваивает им стиль, мне нужно изменить параметры name и autor во время компиляции, как это реализовать?
[image: вот сама кнопка]

```xml
<Window x:Class="SoundPlayer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SoundPlayer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="700"
        Width="700" Height="400"
        Background="#FF212121">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="songStyle">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,1,2,1"/>
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Name="borderSongButton" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FF324D95">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="numberTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="1."
                                               FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               Foreground="#FF9B9B9B"/>
                                    <Grid x:Name="songInfoGrid" Grid.Column="3">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="80"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="80" MaxWidth="150"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="nameTitleTextBlock" Text="Название:"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Foreground="#FF9B9B9B"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="songNameTextBlock" Text="NAME"
                                                   Grid.Row="1" FontSize="25"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF272727"/>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#FF9B9B9B" Width="1"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="autorTitleTextBlock" Text="Исполнитель:"
                                                   Foreground="#FF9B9B9B" Grid.Column="2"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="autorTextBlock" Text="autor"
                                                   Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="1"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   FontSize="25" Foreground="#FF272727"/>
                                        <Border Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#FF9B9B9B" Width="1"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="durationTextBlock" Text="00:00"
                                                   Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   Foreground="#FF272727" FontSize="20"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Button x:Name="optionButton" Grid.Column="5" Height="30"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="323*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="800*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FF252525" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10"/>
        <Border x:Name="playlistBorder" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FF242742" CornerRadius="10"/>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF242742" CornerRadius="10"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid x:Name="sortGrid" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="#FF3A3A3A" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="sortComboBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="по названию"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="по длине"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="по исполнителю"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <Button x:Name="sortButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
            </Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="playListScrollView" Grid.Row="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel x:Name="playListStackPanel" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="127*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="navigationGrid" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="20"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="currentTimeTextBlock" Text="00:00" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="maxTimeTextBlock" Text="00:00" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFA8A8A8" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="playerButtonsGrid" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <Button x:Name="pauseButton" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="4"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="volumeBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#FF242742" CornerRadius="10"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="volumeGrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="VolumeScroll" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="switchVolumeButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddSongButtonToPlayList();
}

public void AddSongButtonToPlayList()
{
    Button songButton = new Button();
    songButton.Style = this.Resources["songStyle"] as Style;
    //изменение name и autor
    playListStackPanel.Children.Add(songButton);
}
```

Comment: Предтавьте ваш код, будьте так добры.

Comment: @Дмитрий добавил, но это тестовый вариант метода, для проверки

Comment: `создает несколько кнопок и присваивает им стиль` - нужен вот этот код

Comment: Не устану повторять. Хватит использовать WPF так, будто вы разрабатываете WinForms! Научитесь использовать базовые его механизмы, а именно XAML и привязки. Вы не должны в коде делать кнопки, вы должны в коде делать коллекцию с данными, которая будет привязана и по которой **сам** WPF построит UI.

Comment: Покажите всю разметку со стилями и весь код, и скажите, что хотите получить, так же опишите. какую именно задачу вы решаете. Чтобы не пришлось догадываться, что вы хотите получить. Вы уехали не туда, и чтобы вас вернуть, нужно начать с начала. Я могу вам помочь в этом, но мне нужно максимум информации.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275459/373567 пример привязки листбокса к коллекции

Comment: @aepot хочу сделать простой аудио плеер. Пользователь указывает папку, там музыка. На основе каждого трека создается кнопка для его запуска, вроде все.

Comment: Ваша главная ошибка в том, что вы начали наводить красоту, но при этом не позаботились о функциональной части приложения. Получилась весьма сложная структура в интерфейсе, которая ничего не умеет. Еще вы перепутали `ScrollBar` и `ProgressBar`. Попробую без наворотов сделать пример. А вы уж сами его вкрутите потом в свой интерфейс.

Comment: @aepot хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтож, вы мне показали дизайн без начинки, я вам покажу начинку без дизайна.

### Простой аудиоплеер в WPF

**Решение может:**

- Переходить по каталогам на текущем диске
- Добавлять MP3 файл в плейлист - двойной клик по файлу в левой панели
- Воспроизводить файл из плейлиста - двойной клик по файлу в плейлисте или кнопка Play
- Воспроизводить следующий файл, если текущий закончился автоматически
- Ставить воспроизведение на паузу - кнопка Pause
- Показывать, сколько времени прошло, продолжительность трека и прогресс воспроизведения в `ProgressBar`
- Менять позицию воспроизведения при клике на прогрессбар
- Регулировать громкость

Может приложение не много, но и не мало. Я старался сделать так, чтобы пример выглядел как можно проще, но при этом показать самые основные принципы, которые вы сможете переиспользовать при дальнейшей разработке.

*Я выбрал стандартный `MediaPlayer` в качестве аудиодвижка для простоты примера, но он мало чего умеет. Советую присмотреться к библиотеке **NAudio**.*

В основе построения приложения лежит шаблон проектирования MVVM. Я не буду вдаваться в детали и рассказывать, что это такое, но вы можете почитать в других моих ответах, например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567) или [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567). Там же вы найдете информацию про вспомогательные классы, показанные ниже.

**Прямо отвечая на ваш вопрос** - как менять данные в интерфейсе из кода, отвечу, что надо сделать следующие шаги:

- Создать класс, в котором разместить свойство, являющееся источником данных для контрола. Например в решении ниже такой класс - `MainViewModel`
- Класс, содержащий нужное свойство должен реализовывать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`. У меня реализация интерфейса наследуется из класса `NotifyPropertyChanged`, представленного ниже.
- Свойство, которое предоставляет данные должно оповещать интерфейс об изменениях данныз посредством вызова события `PropertyChanged` передавая в качестве аргумента своё имя. Данный механизм у меня реализован в методе `OnPropertyChanged()` где имя вызвавшего метод свойства автоматически подсталяется компилятором с помощью аттрибута `[CallerMemberName]`.
- Контрол нужно привязать к свойству с помощью `Binding` например `<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>`
- Чтобы `Binding` понял, где искать нужное свойство с данными, окну надо задать `DataContext`. Это сделано у меня в конструкторе окна `MainWindow`.

Далее можно менять значение свойства, а контрол при этом будет обновлять своё содержимое автоматически.

С первого взгляда может показаться сложным, но оно того стоит, потому что полностью избавляет от войны с контролами в C# коде. Я вообще не работаю с контролами в коде, все контролы находятся в разметке. Есть конечно в коде `MediaPlayer`, он контрол, но я его не использую в разметке интерфейса.

Теперь к делу

#### Вспомогательные классы

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

#### Структуры данных

```cs
public enum FileItemType
{
    File,
    Directory
}

public class FileItem
{
    public FileItemType Type { get; }
    public string FilePath { get; }
    public string Name => Path.GetRelativePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory, FilePath);

    public FileItem(FileItemType type, string path)
    {
        Type = type;
        FilePath = path;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) 
        => obj is FileItem item && FilePath.Equals(item.FilePath);

    public override int GetHashCode() 
        => FilePath.GetHashCode();
}
```

#### View Model класс

Здесь весь основной код

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    const string fileMask = "*.mp3";
    private readonly MediaPlayer _player = new MediaPlayer();
    private List<FileItem> _files;
    private string _currentDirectory;
    private ICommand _changeDirCommand;
    private ICommand _PlayCommand;
    private ObservableCollection<FileItem> _playList;
    private bool _isPlaying;
    private bool _isPaused = true;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private Task _playingTask;
    private FileItem _currentTrack;
    private TimeSpan _duration;
    private TimeSpan _position;
    private ICommand _pauseResumeCommand;

    public double Volume
    { 
        get => _player.Volume; 
        set => _player.Volume = value; 
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get => _duration; 
        set
        {
            if (value != _duration)
            {
                _duration = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan Position
    {
        get => _position;
        set
        {
            if (value != _position)
            {
                _position = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public FileItem CurrentTrack
    {
        get => _currentTrack;
        set
        {
            _currentTrack = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get => _isPlaying;
        set
        {
            _isPlaying = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool IsPaused
    {
        get => _isPaused;
        set
        {
            _isPaused = value;

            if (_isPaused)
            {
                if (_player.CanPause)
                    _player.Pause();
            }
            else
                _player.Play();

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<FileItem> Files
    {
        get => _files;
        set
        {
            _files = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double Progress
    {
        get
        {
            if (_player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
            {
                Duration = _player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
                Position = _player.Position;
                return Position.TotalSeconds * 100 / Duration.TotalSeconds;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_player.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
            {
                Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value * Duration.TotalSeconds / 100);
                _player.Position = Position;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FileItem> PlayList
    {
        get => _playList;
        set
        {
            _playList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string CurrentDirectory
    {
        get => _currentDirectory;
        set
        {
            _currentDirectory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void LoadDirectories()
    {
        CurrentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        var files = new List<FileItem>();
        if (Path.GetPathRoot(CurrentDirectory) != CurrentDirectory)
            files.Add(new FileItem(FileItemType.Directory, Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, "..")));
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(CurrentDirectory).Select(d => new FileItem(FileItemType.Directory, d)));
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(CurrentDirectory, fileMask).Select(f => new FileItem(FileItemType.File, f)));
        Files = files;
    }

    public ICommand ChangeDirCommand => _changeDirCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is FileItem item)
        {
            switch (item.Type)
            {
                case FileItemType.Directory:
                    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(item.Name);
                    LoadDirectories();
                    break;
                case FileItemType.File:
                    PlayList.Add(item);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
        
    public ICommand PlayCommand => _PlayCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        Play();
    });

    public ICommand PauseResumeCommand => _pauseResumeCommand ??= new RelayCommand(_ =>
    {
        if (!IsPlaying)
            Play();
        else
            IsPaused = !IsPaused;
    }, _ => CurrentTrack != null);

    private async void Play()
    {
        if (CurrentTrack == null)
            return;
        if (_cts != null)
        {
            _cts?.Cancel();
            await _playingTask;
        }
        _playingTask = PlayAsync(CurrentTrack);
    }

    private void PlayNext()
    {
        if (PlayList.Count > 1)
        {
            int index = PlayList.IndexOf(CurrentTrack);
            if (index < PlayList.Count - 1)
            {
                CurrentTrack = PlayList[index + 1];
                Play();
            }
            else
                IsPaused = true;
        }
        else 
            IsPaused = true;
    }

    private async Task PlayAsync(FileItem item)
    {
        IsPlaying = true;
        _player.Open(new Uri(item.FilePath));
        IsPaused = false;
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Progress));
                    await Task.Delay(500, _cts.Token);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        _cts = null;
        IsPlaying = false;
        Progress = 0;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _player.MediaEnded += (s, e) => { _cts?.Cancel(); PlayNext(); };
        PlayList = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>();
        LoadDirectories();
    }
}
```

#### Подключение View Model к окну

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
        Loaded += (s, e) => vm.Start();
    }
}
```

#### Кликабельный прогрессбар

Нужен, чтобы можно было в него тыкать и менять текущее время воспроизведения

```cs
public class EditableProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public EditableProgressBar() : base() 
        => Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        Value = e.GetPosition(this).X * (Maximum - Minimum) / ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

#### Разметка интерфейса

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Directory">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, StringFormat=[{0}]}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangeDirCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding PlayList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTrack}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.PlayCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position, StringFormat=mm\\:ss}" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <local:EditableProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding Progress}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Duration, StringFormat=mm\\:ss}" Padding="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Slider VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Value="{Binding Volume}" Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Margin="10" FontSize="20" Command="{Binding PauseResumeCommand}" Padding="10 0">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xF5B0;"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="True"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPaused}" Value="False"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xF8AE;"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*Данный ответ написан под музыку, которую играл этот плеер.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Решение в сборе на Яндекс.Диске - https://disk.yandex.ru/d/YYS4u6M7viiLug*

Comment: Хороший ответ, хоть и с нарушениями MVVM, ведь `MediaPlayer`, это View. Конечно, для понимания "и так сойдет", но все же. И кстати по поводу понимания, вот уверен, что новичок, который пытался играться со стилями кнопки, чтоб изменить так текст, вряд ли что-либо поймет без объяснения каждой строки, может стоит больше пояснений делать, раз на то пошло?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да я уже к концу реализации только понял, что это контрол. :) Я еще сейчас прямой ответ на вопрос из топика допишу.

Comment: Тут самое главное пояснения для автора вопроса сделать, ибо сейчас, как по мне, этот ответ равнозначен тому, если бы мы просто дали ссылку на GitHub и сказали бы "разбирайся", ведь в ответе что? Код и "что этот код может". С нарушением то фиг с ним, его если автор поймет, сам исправит, ибо чего там, простая инверсия, чтоб VM отдавал событие, на которое подпишется V, но вот объяснение, ну не поймет человек не знающий всех тонкостей...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ допилено

Comment: @EvgeniyZ сижу голову ломаю, интересно стало, как сделать, чтобы при тыке в прогресс бар он перескакивал на место, где я ткнул. В смысле, я хочу поймать тык, высчитать из него время, дать это плееру, чтобы он перестроился на новое время, в результате чего прогресс бар бы встал в нужный прогресс. Просто ищу способ захвата координат тыка мышкой. Или это только через обработчик собития сделать можно?

Comment: А разве это не функционал слайдера?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ решил наследованием от прогрессбара, так как слайдер дал не совсем то поведение, которое я ожидал, и привести к нужному поведению у меня не получилось. Обновил решение. Попутно прикрутил регулятор громкости.

Comment: @aepot огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ. Думаю, благодаря таким людям, как вы комьюнити и живет. Я сейчас читаю Троелсона, прошел пару глав по wpf, но не дошел до mvvm и не углубился в привязки, получается поторопился, буду наверстывать. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @ИльяВолков [вот еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275459/373567), может оказаться полезным.

Comment: @aepot О каком именно поведении идет речь? Допустим, набросал на скорую руку [такой](https://pastebin.com/WEsKUsyX) стиль, который +- повторяет стандартный прогресс бар без анимаций, получится [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9yGh.gif) эффект, вроде то, что и требовалось, не? Для чего просто изобретать новый контрол не пойму.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ похоже на правду, да. А у меня такое не получилось. Оно при клике прыгало не в точку, где ткнул, а на определенный шаг. Кстати, я еще подумал, потом еще подумал, и решил, что драггинг мышкой прогрессбара здесь - лишнее. Не совсем понятно, как должен вести себя плеер при драггинге. Явно не должен не перестраиваться в реалтайме, иначе будет много мусора в колонках. Поэтому пожалуй оставлю решение с наследованием. Но всё равно спасибо, уже разбираю ваше решение. Однозначно полезно, и после допила можно получить идеальное в плане UX решение.

Comment: @aepot Чтоб переносило в нужную точку, должно быть выполнено несколько условий `IsMoveToPointEnabled = true` и должен быть верно написанный `Track`. `при драггинге` - я бы ставил на паузу (либо не выполнял каких-либо действий) до тех пор, пока не будет отжата кнопка мыши.