# WPF Как предоставить пользователю возможность работать с файлами через само приложение?

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, мне нужна ваша помощь =) Коротко о сути вопроса:
У меня есть готовая программа по типу словаря "жестового языка"
Не знаю как реализовать чтобы пользователь мог добавлять в самом додаку свои фразы, слова и т.д. ?  + должен бить поиск слов и история котороя должна сохраняться в какой нибуть текстовый файл.
Сама реализация программы такова:
Список кнопок которые при клике задают MediaElement путь к видео и он их воспроизводит.
Надеюсь я правильно описал суть вопроса. Всем зарание спасибо =D

Comment: Не совсем понятно, на что вы хотите получить ответ. У вас нет вопроса, у вас есть только "реализация". В чем трудности? В чем проблема?  
На вопрос "Можно ли..." - можно.

Comment: Не знаю как реализовать чтобы пользователь мог добавлять в самом додаку свои фразы, слова и т.д. ?

Comment: _сохраняться в ... файл_ - ну, что ещё нужно? Пишите в файл и читайте из него.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov
Простите ... Но я работаю на WPF около недели .... Я не очень понимаю о чем вы говорите и как ето делать (
Возможно есть какая-то статья об етом? Если знаете поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: WPF с файлами не связан никак, изучайте c# и стандартную библиотеку. Из литературы, лучший экскурс в BCL из того что видел — книга Албахари

Comment: Понял. Спасибо буду читать)

Comment: Да проще, изучите классы `File` и `Directory` из пространства имён `System.IO`, что умеют и как пользоваться. Всё что нужно для работы с файлами там есть. Примеров тоже полинтернета.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277233/373567 небольшой пример работы с файлами.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, буду изучать)