# Ошибка при добавлении ссылки в Visual Studio на WindowsBase

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, dllimport

Моя задача: Использовать в проекте класс MediaPlayer из using System.Windows.Media. Я подключил PresetationCore.dll и при выполнении функции Open, студия требует ссылку на WindowsBase
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**При попытке подключить в проект WindowsBase происходит вот это:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю как решить, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Тип проекта какой? Версия дотнета какая? Класс, про который вы говорите - для WPF. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277233/373567

Comment: У меня версия .NET 5.0, а касательно  того решения, мне нужно использовать только этот класс

Comment: Удалите ссылки, добавленные вручную, этот устаревший способ добавлять референсы на компоненты дотнета не стоит больше использовать, во всяком случае для добавления битблиотек .NET SDK. Вместо этого откройте .cproj файл и напишите там `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` рядом с `<UseWindowsForms>`. Нужные библиотеки подключатся автоматически. Но я не уверен, что вы сможете использовать MediaPlayer без WPF окна.

Comment: Я использую Winforms, это же WPF?

Comment: Вы хотите использовать `System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer`. Этот класс находится в WPF. PresentationCore.dll - это основная библиотека WPF.

Comment: Я это и хочу использовать

Comment: Так используйте. Я не понимаю, что не так. Мне только не ясно, зачем вам WPF контрол, который вы не сможете использовать в окне. Какую задачу вы решаете - тоже храните в секрете.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало, а где я использую Wpf конрол ?

Comment: Я просто хочу запускать музыку с возможностью поставить на паузу

Comment: Так бы и сказали, в таком случае MediaPlayer - худшее решение. Есть хорошая библиотека [NAudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio), на ее основе даже плееры есть, например в библиотеке [SIL.Media](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SIL.Media/), например [этот](https://github.com/sillsdev/libpalaso/blob/master/SIL.Media/Naudio/AudioPlayer.cs). Я сам последнюю не пробовал, но там есть всякие разные контролы. Что касается NAudio - это лучший выбор для работы с аудио. Так что попробуйте отказаться от WPF.

Comment: `а где я использую Wpf конрол` System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer - это WPF контрол. Об этом я написал в первом же комментарии выше. Но вы как бы не заметили.

Comment: Спасибо тогда, попробую использовать  NAUDIO