# Добавление списка файлов из каталога в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

Вылезают ошибки

1. `Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" в "System.Windows.Controls.ListView"`
2. `Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "ListView".   pr_5`

Понятно, что из-за первой лезет и вторая. Подскажите как можно это дело исправить или как проще создать это приложение, руки опускаются уже

```
private void btn_path_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (dialogResult.HasFlag(System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK))
    {
        tbx_path.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }

    lw_SpisokPhoto = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tbx_path.Text)
        .Where(x => x.EndsWith(".jpg") || x.EndsWith(".png"))
        .ToList();
    if (lw_SpisokPhoto.AlternationCount == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    im_gallery.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(lw_SpisokPhoto[0]));
}
```

Comment: Прочитайте про привязки, очень простой механизм, прям очень. В WPF проекте вы не должны хотеть использовать контролы в коде, не должно быть `im_gallery.Source` и так далее. Данные в одном месте (простые классы), а вид в другом (простой XAML). `System.Windows.Forms` - это видеть в WPF проекте не кажется странным? Ведь это компоненты `WinForms`, а не WPF. Вот это тоже `lw_SpisokPhoto[0]`, ну подумайте логически, что вы хотите тут? Наверно взять один из объектов, что в нем, верно? Так почему не `lw_SpisokPhoto.Items[0]`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ насколько мне известно, `FolderBrowserDialog` отсутствует в `Microsoft.Win32` спейсе. Поэтому здесь проще всего Winforms тащить.

Comment: @aepot Проще, да. Правильней? Нет. В NuGet есть сторонние пакеты, которые все это возвращают, без форм, например одна из популярных - `Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в одном случае тащишь нугет либу с собой, в другом установленную внутри самого дотнета используешь. Разница невелика. Можно самому на винапи написать эти диалоги, особо ничего сложного. На самом деле для ученика это даже неважно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lw_SpisokPhoto` это контрол, а не коллекция, его коллекция это свойство `ItemsSource`.

```
private void btn_path_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    var dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (dialogResult.HasFlag(System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK))
    {
        tbx_path.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }

    string[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tbx_path.Text)
        .Where(x => x.EndsWith(".jpg") || x.EndsWith(".png"))
        .ToArray();
    lw_SpisokPhoto.ItemsSource = files;
    if (files.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    im_gallery.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(files[0]));
}
```

Пример работы с файлами в листбоксе есть еще [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277233/373567).

Comment: @Котька дополнил ответ, упростил код.

Comment: так, я дурак. а операция ToArray?

Comment: @Котька здесь просто, зачем делать список, если не нужно добавлять и удалять элементы, поэтому массив. Массив более легковесный и быстрее работает.

Comment: логично, спасибо вам большое

Comment: здравствуйте, не нашла способа как вам лично написать. хотела узнать, а вы работаете с sql?

Comment: @Котька здравствуйте, нет