# У меня есть ListBox и я хочу чтоб при нажатии на каждый его элемент происходило событие, как?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть программа которая открывает файлы разных форматов, идея была в том чтобы отображать в новом окне ранее открытые файлы. Эти файлы хранятся у меня в `json` файле. В новом окне у меня есть `ListBox` и он отображает название этих файлов друг за другом. Файл это объект класса, у него есть поля `Название` и `Путь`.

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на элемент `ListItem` файл открывался в предыдущем (`MainWindow`) окне, как это реализовать программно?

Какие средства лучше использовать?

```
public partial class TempPage : Window
{
    public TempPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void templist(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileJs fileJs = new FileJs();
        fileJs.ReadFile();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileJs.books.Count; i++)
        {
            listbook.Items.Add(fileJs.books[i].Name);
            
        }
    }}
```

Это новое окно в котором выводятся ранее добавленные файлы
`FileJs` - это класс в котором реализована запись и чтение `json` файла

```
internal class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    public Book(string name, string filePath)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }
}
```

Это класс файла.

У меня есть алгоритм открытия нужных мне файлов в `MainWindow`, они открываются нормально через диалоговое окно, но как мне реализовать открытие через нажатие во втором окне, у меня есть доступ к пути файла.

Comment: `Какие средства лучше использовать?` - вам по уму или костыли? Если костыли, то просто подпишитесь на событие `SelectionChanged` и делайте все, что вашей душе угодно. Если по уму, используйте привязки, с ними вам достаточно просто в свойстве, в его `set` указать нужное. А еще умнее, использовать генерацию кода, где вам просто надо будет сделать свойство и метод с нужными названиями. P.S. Не бросайте старые вопросы, SO это не форум, а сайт, где сообщество совместными силами собирает интересное и полезное не только вам, но и будущим читателям. Лучше удалите вопрос, если он неактуален.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277233/373567