# Как при нажатии на определенную кнопку открывать определенный файл?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
foreach (string file_name in Directory.GetFiles(file_Path))
            {
                button.Content = file_name.Remove(0, directory + 9);
                button.Uid = Convert.ToString(i);
                i++;
                files.Add(file_name);
                Items.Add(button.Content);
            }
            // нужно, чтобы при нажатии на определенную кнопку открывалась конкретно этот файл с текстом
        }
        void Item_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Button btn = (Button)sender;
            //MessageBox.Show((string)btn.DataContext);
            //current_file = sender.;

            file_text = File.ReadAllText(files[Convert.ToInt32(button.Uid)]);
            List list = new();
            MainWindow main_window = new();
            main_window.Hide();
            list.Show();
            Close();
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать так, чтобы открывался первый файл txt если я нажимаю на первую кнопку, второй txt если на вторую? По идее нужно использовать привязку, но у меня не сработало

Comment: Пример работы с файлами в листбоксе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277233/373567