# Не могу понять в чём проблема с textBox в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, textbox

этот код на c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Un4seen.Bass;
using Un4seen.Bass.AddOn.Tags;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using TagLib;

private void songsListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (songsListView.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string selectedSong = importedSongs[songsListView.SelectedIndex];
            textBox.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedSong);
        }
    }
```

a этот код на xml

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,217,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="32" FontSize="22" TextChanged="songsListView_SelectionChanged"/>
```

vs не нравится почему-то textBox из c# кода и выводит ошибку:CS0103 Имя "textBox" не существует в текущем контексте.

Comment: Можно весь код?

Comment: `textBox` - это что? Наверно имя конкретного контрола, да? Ок... А где это имя? Где `x:Name = "textBox"` в XAML? И да, советую учить привязки данных, в WPF так, как вы делаете, мало кто пишет приложение. Ну и советую научиться позиционировать объекты правильно, видите большой `Margin` - сразу делаете что-то не то, не удивляйтесь потом тому, что объекты не там, где надо, и при изменении размеров окна съезжают с нужных мест.

Comment: В xaml коде не было вообще имени, я добавил и ошибка исчезла

Comment: У вас событие изменения текста изменяет текст. Что-то где-то напутали, что такое `songsListView`. Что этот обработчик должен сделать? Возможно [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1277233/373567) вам поможет разобраться. А то вы пишете об ошибке, но не пишете, что хотите сделать. Разберитесь сначала с тем, что на самом деле нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить к `TextBox` параметр `x:Name="textBox"`, тогда можно будет обращаться к `TextBox` из кода C#